# How to zip individual files from different directories in one line?

Tags: files, directory, zip

I want to zip numerous files from different directories(paths) in one line. How can I do that?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm probably misunderstanding you, but you just specify the paths one after the other:

```
zip foo.zip /path/to/first/file /path/to/second/file
```